# Count items in Infopath field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I created a form in Infopath with a rich text box field. The field is used to keep a list of usernames (first and last). I want to be able to keep a of count each entry and keep a tally. I then want to use that total # of entries to add or subtract from other fields.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you add an example of the data?

Comment: List of names John Doe, John Doe2, John Doe3....
Want to keep a running count of "John Doe" entered in the text field

Answer (score 0):

Is the rich text box field just a large string? If so you could just use python's built in split function, and either split by ("\r\n"), or (",").
Example:

```
u = "Bob, Michael, Jean"
x = u.split(",")
```

X will be a list of usernames. If you are using line breaks for each new username, then replace (",") with ("\r\n").

Now to count the items in a list you just need to iterate on the list you created with a for loop.
Example:

```
b = 0
u = "Bob, Michael, Jean"
x = u.split(",")

for i in x:
    b += 1 // b will be the number of usernames
```

Comment: The rich text field will be a list of names, 2 per line (first_last1, first_last2) that will be entered in Sharepoint.  The list is unknown to me until it's entered in Sharepoint. Not sure how to separate. Don't see a split function within Infopath.